# Is $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ rational?

Tags: rationality-testing

In §2.2 of [her essay on mathematical morality](http://www.cheng.staff.shef.ac.uk/morality/morality.pdf), Eugenia Cheng includes the following example:

> 6. Why is it possible for an irrational to the power of an irrational to be rational?
>
>    Here is a nice little proof that it is possible:
>
>    > Consider $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$.
>    >
>    > If it is rational, we are done.
>    >
>    > If it is irrational, consider
>    >     $$ \left(\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}\right)^\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2}^2=2.$$

However, as Cheng notes, this doesn't tell us whether $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ itself is rational or not. So which is it?

Comment: An [archived version of the essay](https://web.archive.org/web/20240000000000*/https://eugeniacheng.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/cheng-morality.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is irrational (in fact it is transcendental). This can be shown using the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem)

By the theorem, where $a$ and $b$ are both algebraic with $a \not \in \{0,1\}$ and $b$ irrational, $a^b$ is transcendental. Transcendental numbers are necessarily irrational.