# if $x^x$ is rational, is $x$ also rational?

Tags: irrational-numbers

Assume that $x$ is a real positive number.

I tried to manipulate the equation $x^x=p/q$ with $p,q$ integers but couldn't really prove or disprove it. Is there any counter examples or this is true? Sorry if this is a trivial question.

Comment: X is real right?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1842348/274

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez That link doesn't answer this question.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez so, that link says that *algebraic* to the power of algebraic irrational must be transcendental, but that doesn't say anything about transcendental to the power of transcendental.  Does there yet exist a transcendental number who when taken to the power of itself yields a rational number?

Comment: For $\pi$ and $e$ , it is unknown.